# Laravel conditional eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this query.

```
return $this->model->with( [ 'items' => function($query){
  $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
}])
->where("org_id",$org_id)
->where('invisible','=',FALSE)
->orderBy('description', 'asc')->get();
```

I would like to find out if its possible to check if any records where returned from the `items` model. If no records where returned, that it would not append the Group to the result

At the moment Im getting some Group records containing no items.

Hope that make sense.

Comment: why not you check after this query as `if(is_null($result->items)){....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` for this. try this out,

```
return $this->model->with('items')
->whereHas('items',fuction ($query){
   $query->where('invisible','=',FALSE)->orderBy('description', 'ASC');
})
->where("org_id",$org_id)
->where('invisible','=',FALSE)
->orderBy('description', 'asc')->get();
```

Hope this helps